Calling TranslateX or RotateX on Page does not affect NavigationPage Navbar, but rotates only page content
I am currently trying MAUI first time. And I am stuck with one problem. In my app I used FlyoutPage.Detail = NavigationPage. Using handlers of the Flyout page I made simple animation. While Opening the Flyout drawer I get coefficient of opening and TranslateX underlying Detail Page (my NavigationPage) to coefficient * 100. In the end, I get working animation. But TranslateX or also RotateX Property changes affect only client area of that page (without including NavBar). Seems Navigation Page is designed differently on Maui.
Attached images:


If you see there my toolbar button did not move to right, Only the content of page (Button) moved. There are also related problems with status bar translucency (also not behave as in xamarin). But that is a separate question. So how can I achieve moving NavBar also to rigth? Would appreciate any help. Thanks
I could not find any solution from Google yet. Searched about customizing pages and controls via Handlers. But no success still.

I see the images and all but i still don't get what you are asking to be honest, please explain further may be add some code to help us understand your question further

@FreakyAli i dont know which part of code to add. It is only a flyout page which has NavigationPage in Detail property. My question is if you see in images when i slide flyout drawer to half, it moves Detail page to the right side also (I used TranslationX = ). It is shown in xamarin that settings button is moved. But in maui (TranslationX = ) does not affect to navbar items. In simple: "Try calling  TranslationX =  on NavigationPage  with toolbar items". Toolbar items will not be Translated by x

Could you please include in your question the relevant code about  the XAML  or code behind of your flyout page? And how do you set the Translation or Rotation for the page.
